# SQL Server Convert US date format to UK during import?

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data that come out of Tableau in a .CSV but the date field is in US format.

Is there a way for me to set it to tell SQL during the import that the source is US using the SQL import text wizard? Edit Mappings -> edit SQL?

If I don't touch anything and do a straight import the date is imported as text, if i change the mapping from navcharacter to date its imported in UK format but the months/days are the wrong way round.

It gets some right i.e.

if the source date date is 1/3/2021 it will convert to 2021-03-01
if the date is 1/30/2021 it will realise it can't use the same method and correctly go to 2021-01-30

Comment: 2 Options I can think of off the top of my head. 1. You could convert csv to Excel and then "fix" the datetime field to be ISO8601 notation and than import that. 2. You could import and use a varchar field into a new table and then write an INSERT/SELECT statement that parses the date varchar value to ISO8601 notation and cast it as a Date.

Comment: When dealing with dates, **always** import as date column. If things are backwards during import, that is something to fix in the import tool, but we haven't seen enough in the question to help yet.

Comment: Use a `LOGIN` with the language set to `ENGLISH`. Otherwise import the data into a staging data, with the columns set to `(n)varchar` and then explicitly `CONVERT` your data to the correct data type in the `INSERT` into your production table using the relevant style code; `103` in the case when convert to a `date`. *Note that your dates won't be stored with a "format" in SQL Server, as date and time data types have no format property (it's stored as binary data). It is the presentation layer's responsibility to format the data for the end user.*

Comment: @Igor data is too big to open in excel, other wise that is where I would be doing the whole thing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the data is being imported as date column, what else do you need to know

Comment: @Larnu it is set to English, the problem is it doesn't recognise that the data its importing is in the US format

Comment: `data is too big to open in excel, other wise that is where I would be doing the whole thing.` ← Excel can handle a lot of data. What is too big? How many records / columns? Make sure you use .xlsx (not xls).

Comment: Actually, rereading your qusetion, it doesn't make sense. You expect `'1/3/2021'` to be `2021-03-01` but `'1/30/2021'` to be `2021-01-30`. Those are 2 different formats. How do *you* know that `'1/3/2021'` is supposed to be `2021-03-01` and not `2021-01-03`? The problem is you are mixing formats. As a result you have no idea what those dates *really* are and thus, I am afraid, they have lost their meaning. I would, personally, import any ambiguous dates as `NULL`, as a `NULL` value is better than a wrong value. For your data, that would be any dates where the month and day are <= 12.

Comment: @igor 1.5 million rows and growing each week,

Comment: The point is you need to fix the data before it is inserted into the final/destination table. It is matter of figuring out where/how you can best do that in your situation. There are options available to you but you need to figure out what steps to take next.

Comment: 1.5 million rows is something Excel can handle. `... and growing each week` So you need a solution that will execute this import repeatedly? You will have to create a manual process or you might have to create a console app or something to do it for you. What you pick depends on what you are able to create (your skill set) and trade that off with time it takes to create. Good luck.

Comment: @Larnu by looking up the unique identifier for that row in the source data and other systems. And also because its telling me things have happened in the future i.e. Its telling me jobs have been completed on 2021-12-1.  and if  I use DATEADD / DATEPART to show the weekending date it tells me the week ending data for 2021-12-01 is  2021-12-5. which confirms its in the YYYY-MM-DD. Ambiguous dates would be anything between the 1st and 12th of the month i.e. 40% of my data.

Comment: Then I would import your data into a staging table, and then `JOIN` that data to your other table that denotes the format and then use a `CASE` expression to convert explicitly. Something like `CASE OT.DateFormat WHEN 'us' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,ST.DateString,101) WHEN 'gb' THEN TRY_CONVERT(date,ST.DateString,103)  END` (where `OT` is the **O**ther **T**able and `ST` is the **S**taging **T**able).

Comment: Go back to the people generating the Tableau report and have them output the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.  If there is a time included - then output in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format.  Then - you don't have to worry about either US or British formats.  And yes - that is a trivial fix to be done in Tableau.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the dates to a table and store them as strings, then convert them to DATETIME using the string style you want from the the [CONVERT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) function, and push those updated dates to your persistent table.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/3/2021',101) AS 'US'
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/3/2021',103) AS 'British/French'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME,'3/1/2021',101) AS 'US'
    ,CONVERT(DATETIME,'3/1/2021',103) AS 'British/French'
```

| US | British/French |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00.000 |